# how could i make Emailfield case insensitive on django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

i'm new at django and i run into this little issue when at the moment to check if there is the same email address on the db  it doesn't take into account if it has a different letter case configuration, is there any method to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can lowercase the field on comparisons (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17561#comment:7)

```
from django.db import models


class EmailField(models.EmailField):
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = super(EmailField, self).get_prep_value(value)
        if value is not None:
            value = value.lower()
        return value
```